# entering a string to be used as a formula , in c#

Tags: c#

I've found the shunting yard algorithm, but  it feels like case is a little bit different.
What if the formula your entering has variables that you want to use in another formula

you enter

```
cout<<"enter string"<<endl;
cin>>f;
```

and you enter f as

```
3 * (X*X) + 2*X + 7
```

and you use that **string** and parse it to find the root, for example.

Comment: What is your question? Please use proper punctuation and capitalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is hard to understand what you are looking for, it hints at the ability to evaluate strings as formulas. If your looking for an Eval like solution, take a look at [nCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/). Stealing from their webpage:

```
Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```

It also allows you to use parameters, like

```
e.Parameters["X"] = 10;
```

and then use X as part of your string to evaluate.

It let's you convert a string representing a formula into it's final value. If you are not asking about interpreting strings at formulas then I am at a loss for what you are asking. I recommend revising your question to better articulate the inputs and outputs of your proposed functionality.

Comment: i tried this already but it won' work if the string has a variable say 

"X*X*X + 5" or something like that

Comment: @stonybrooknick that's what the Parameters dictionary is for. "e.Parameters["X"] = 10;" should set the varaible to something, then you can use "X*X*X" in your string.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that comes to my mind is, may be you can create a valid C# code from that string at runtime and make it compile, and make it execute. For example your code cam become in memory like

```
using namespace FormulaCalculator
{
     public class Calculator 
     {
         public static object Calculate() 
         {
             return 3 * (X*X) + 2*X + 7 ; //where X is replaced value at runtime.
         }
     }
}
```

Compile this with [CodeDome](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f1dfsbhc.aspx) in in-memory assembly and run. Here an example [Example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655)

`object resultOfFormula = FormulaCalculator.Calculator.Calculate()`